# How can I change the short description Facebook uses for a link?

Tags: facebook

When I post this link: https://www.islandprotravel.no/lp/leiebil.html
Facebook takes the short description from the german website instead of taking it from the meta tag og:description.

Here is what I have in the source code:

[image]

and the text shown is this one:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The reason the old text showed up is because Facebook caches the scraped information. You can refresh the cache for a specific URL using the Sharing Debugger.

See: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.islandprotravel.no%2Flp%2Fleiebil.html